# How to make os_log to print to cli?

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a program (executable binary) in Objective-C that I can run on terminal/cli. When I use `os_log` to log something, it appears on Console app. But I want the log output to appear on the cli when I run the program, just like printf behavior. How to make `os_log` to do that?

Comment: Could you use NSLog; it outputs to Terminal.

Comment: NSLog actually outputs to both os_log and terminal if that's what you want.